# Pandas Datetime keyerror filtering

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I scraped tweets using Snscrape and now trying to filter the dates with pandas. I converted the column to Datetime but I'm getting a `KeyError`:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
startdate = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-24').date()
enddate = pd.to_datetime('2022-03-03').date()
df.loc[startdate:enddate]
```

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.date'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter using the 'Datetime' column as follows:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['Datetime'] >= startdate) & (df['Datetime'] <= enddate)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the dates (noticed I've omitted `.dt.date` at the end):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then you can use `.between` instead of `.loc` for this:

```
filtered = df[df['Datetime'].between('2022-02-24', '2022-03-03')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but I still have the same issue: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Comment: Check the answer now ;)